# Firebase catch exception

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following code that is throwing me some firebase exception in the console if the data that I want to save to firebase is invalid. 
I want to catch it and display it to the screen in a controlled manner rather than finding out from console. 
I dont know why my .catch is not catching any of the firebase exceptions?

```
this.databaseService.saveCodesToFirebase(jsonFromCsv)
  .then(result => {
    this.alertService.alertPopup('Success', 'Code Updated')
  })
  .catch(error => {
    this.errorMessage = 'Error - ' + error.message
  })


saveCodesToFirebase(myObj: Object) {
    let ref = firebase.database().ref();

    let path = this.userService.getCurrentUser().companyId + '/codes/'
    let lastUpdatedPath = this.userService.getCurrentUser().companyId + '/lastUpdated/';

    var updates = {}

    updates[path] = jobObject;
    updates[lastUpdatedPath] = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000);

    return ref.child('codes').update(updates);
}
```

> EXCEPTION: Firebase.update failed: First argument  contains an invalid key () in property 'codes.apple20170318.codes'.  Keys must be
>   non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "/", "[", or "]"

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Provide more details about your data model in the `real time` DB.

Comment: @ErnieKev I'm facing the same. Did you figure out how to overcome that? I even added external global try-catch but it still happening as I have some 'update' calls inside a callback. Is it the only way to put try-catch everywhere? What's the use of firebase's "catch" then?

Answer (score 5):

There's not much to go on here but my best guess is that the object you're passing to `saveCodesToFirebase()` has keys that contain dots in them, like the one shown in the error message: `jobCodes.apple20170318.codes`.

If you want to keep this model you will have to sanitize that object to replace any invalid characters in its keys (and its children keys, recursively) before doing the `update()` operation.

When it comes to catching the exception, you'll have to use a try/catch block. The `.catch()` attached to the promise in this case is only useful to detect errors returned by the server, but here it's the `update()` method itself the one synchronously throwing the exception.

One possible approach would be like this:

```js
try {
  this.databaseService.saveCodesToFirebase(jsonFromCsv)
    .then(result => {
      this.alertService.alertPopup('Success', 'Code Updated')
    })
    .catch(error => {
      this.errorMessage = 'Error - ' + error.message
    })
} catch (error) {
  this.errorMessage = 'Error - ' + error.message
}
```

Comment: I know that this is the case and is easily fixable. However, My goal here is to be able to catch this error somehow by some catch statement.

Answer (score 0):

So, in Javascript you usually should have just one catch clause per try statement. You could achieve what you want using the syntax below:

```
try {
 // some code 
} catch (err) {
    if( err istanceof FirebaseError ) {
        this.errorMessage = 'Error - ' + err.message;
    } else {
        this.errorMessage = 'Error - Generic error';
    }
}
```

you can find more information here in the section [Conditional catch-blocks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch#conditional_catch-blocks)